# URI encoding for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What would be the best way to encode uris like below?

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLDTm1X_c-M
```

I got this saved into the database but now it's returning `400 OpenURI HTTP Error`

How do I get around this?

What is the best way to escape the string like this? I've tried `URI.encode` but not sure whether this should be included in model before save or controller before strong parameters

Comment: What is the encoding purpose, showing the url inside an HTML view? If yes, the view renderer automatically escapes the url for you unless you mark it as `html_safe`, so f.e. `<p><%= record.url %></p>` shouldn't give you problems

Comment: The error seems to occur on this part `= raw @yt_session.video_by(@video.yt_youtube_id).embed_html_with_width(500) if @video.yt_youtube_id.present?`

Comment: @mdesantis It seems like youtube_it gem method of `video_by` is causing this error. I tried escaping the `@video.yt_youtube_id` using `u` but no luck...

Comment: is it for embed youtube video inside your page? if yes, why don't you use `iframe`, like this `<iframe frameborder="0" width="330" height="250" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v<%= @video.yt_youtube_id %>"></iframe>`

Comment: @rony36 I would like to use `youtube_it` gem for it as it allows several different functionalities

Comment: Can you please write in the question a code sample, the output you get and the output expected